# Loop and Save Data

Tags: python, loops

Actually, I am new in Python, so I need more help to handle my data. The next step is make loop for a month data from daily data (one day one file). And then make the variables (numeric) resulted from this program as a new array and save those as a file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output to let us start something with.

Comment: Input file is netcdf file that contain of variable az, ze, rng, tim, pwr, nfft, and pn. From pwr, tim, nfft, and pn, I obtain p_plot. And then I count max value of p_plot. I did for one file, but need help for many files in once running

Comment: @user3346361 Edit your post and write the output sample you desire for your file or files, in order to make us and idea of your needs.

Comment: I'm not going to answer until you go back to the previous post and mark an answer as correct.

Comment: All of the answers are correct, but I can not mark all of them

Comment: @user3346361, you just mark the best one. 

How big are your datasets? you can just slurp in a whole bunch of files into memory, using a three dimensional list, where the third dimension contains tables of files, and the second dimension contains rows for a table, and the first dimension contains columnar information. If that's okay, I'll draft that up into a solution.

Comment: The datasets contain daily data of netcdf data, one file for one day. So, I have 366/365 file for a year.

Answer (score 1):

You can add each of the files i.e., `A1`,`A2`..`Ax` in a list. Then save the list. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like @leeladam said, is better to store the values of your A variables in a list (a nested list, each element of the A list is other list with your data).

Then the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) is the best approach for that task.  Each line of the csv line (row) is an A list and each column is a data comma separated.  With this module you can save the data with Excel format.